# Setting the X Axes Limit in Matplotlib 1.4.3

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I am trying to zoom in on a section of my plot.  I used the following code to produce the high level plot below.

```
fig = poll_df.plot('Start Date', 'Difference',figsize=(12,4),marker='o',linestyle='-',color='purple')


# Now add the debate markers
plt.axvline(x=403+2, linewidth=4, color='grey')
plt.axvline(x=403+10, linewidth=4, color ='grey')
plt.axvline(x=403+21, linewidth=4, color='grey')


plt.show()
```

[image]
The vertical grey bars are in the right locations and I want to zoom in on the plot (basically to show the month of October).  I modified the plot to add the xlim parameters as below.

```
fig = poll_df.plot('Start Date', 'Difference',figsize=(12,4), marker='o',linestyle='-',color='purple',xlim=(403,433))


# Now add the debate markers
plt.axvline(x=403+2, linewidth=4, color='grey')
plt.axvline(x=403+10, linewidth=4, color ='grey')
plt.axvline(x=403+21, linewidth=4, color='grey')


plt.show()
```

However, this gives me a totally different plot (see below).  I have tried all sorts of variations and still can't seem to get it to work.  It looks as if the vertical bars would be in the right places if the axis labels reflected the month of October.

Why did the plot not rescale the x labels?

[image]

Comment: What does `type(poll_df['Start Date'].iloc[0])` return?

Comment: Does it work if you modify 'Start Date' with: `poll_df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(poll_df['Start Date'])`?

Comment: Thanks, your modifications worked and I was able to reference the dates rather than the indices. The first line was as you indicated and then I just used actual dates:
`fig = poll_df.plot('Start Date', 'Difference',figsize=(12,4), marker='o',linestyle='-',color='purple', xlim=('Oct 2012','Nov 2012'))


# Now add the debate markers
plt.axvline(x='Oct 3 2012', linewidth=4, color='grey')
plt.axvline(x='Oct 11 2012', linewidth=4, color ='grey')
plt.axvline(x='Oct 22 2012', linewidth=4, color='grey')

plt.show()`